# How can I edit the content of a file in shell script?

Tags: shell

Are there other alternatives aside from `sed`?
I meant a command that does this in shell script

`cat file1` and it contains the following:

```
How
are
you
```

But suppose I want to change the word "How" into "Who"?

Comment: `vim` in a shell script is ... not the obvious choice, shall we say.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of alternatives to `sed`, but `sed` is probably the tool of choice for this particular operation.  The alternatives include:

- `ed`
- `ex`
- Perl
- Python
- Ruby
- `awk`

The `ed` and `ex` commands are similar:

```
ed ff <<!
g/How/s//Who/g
w
q
!
```

You can write `ex` instead of `ed`.

```
perl -i.bak -p -e 's/\bHow\b/Who/g' ff

awk '{ gsub(/How/, "Who"); print }' ff
```

I'm not fluent enough in Python or Ruby to give idiomatic solutions.

But `sed`, especially GNU `sed` with the `-i` option, is pretty convenient too:

```
sed -i 's/How/Who/g' ff
```

Without the `-i` option (and the `-i` option is not completely idiot-proof, if you've got an idiot like me with symlinks or multiple links to a single file in play), you can use:

```
sed 's/How/Who/g' ff > ff.$$
cp ff.$$ ff
rm -f ff.$$
```

Or, with traps to ensure no residual temporary files:

```
tmp=ff.$$
trap "rm -f $tmp; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15
sed 's/How/Who/g' ff > ff.$$
cp ff.$$ ff
rm -f ff.$$
trap 0
```

Comment: I tried sed but for some reason it replaces a blank line instead of the new word itself inside the file