# How to write shell provision code for a vagrant box to change a file not in the shared folder?

Tags: shell, vagrant

I am setting up a vagrant box to create a django box and i need to make changes to the apache2 vhost configuration in the provision shell code.
how to edit a file in a shell command?

Comment: you could do vagrant ssh in the termianal and then navigate to the directory where your apache2 config file is located with the cd command

Comment: Do you know Google? You type "how to edit a file in a shell command" into their search field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I edit the content of a file in shell script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766429/how-can-i-edit-the-content-of-a-file-in-shell-script)

Answer (score 0):

Most simple is if you can have a copy of the host file configuration that you want to apply to your VM. So on your host machine you have the file and during provisioning you will apply this file on the guest machine.

This can be done using the [File Provisioner](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/file.html) you will add the following in your Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.provision "file", source: "path/to/host_conf_file", destination: "/var/path/to/apache/conf/file"
```